# How to break Printf() in multiple Printf()

Tags: c, printf

Hi can anyone help me to correct this code, the result should be

```
/c=4.000000/
/d=4.0000  /
```

I know by putting the logic in single printf() i will get my result but i am not understanding that how to use two printf() and the varibles will be given by the second printf().
Here is my code:-

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{       
    int a=19,b=4;
    float c,d;
    c=a/b;
    d=a%b;
    printf("/c=%12f/\nd=%");
    printf("-12.4f/",c,d);
    putchar(10);    
    return 0;
}
```

If I change my code to this, I will get the result,

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a=19,b=4;
    float c,d;
    c=a/b;
    d=a%b;
    /*
    printf("/c=%12f/\nd=%");
    printf("-12.4f/",c,d);
    */
    printf("/c=%12f/\n/d=%-12.4f/",c,d);
    putchar(10);    
    return 0;
}
```

but I want to use two printf() statements.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why `putchar(10)` instead of `printf("\n")` (or putting the newline in the existing `printf` call)? Don't use [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).

Comment: You want to print each line with a dedicated printf call?

Comment: And you ***can't*** split up formatting like you want to do. ***Why*** do you want to do that? I can understand if you wanted one `printf` per line of output, but not splitting it illogically like you do.

Comment: I am just experimenting with the printf() function.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "the parameter I am trying to use in the last printf() only". Also please explain what makes you think that it should work; ideally quote from the documentation. Or show code which you have seen use it like that. Are you comparing with a different language than C?

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this:

```
printf("/c=%12f/\nd=%");
printf("-12.4f/",c,d);
```

because you are lying to both `printf`s, in the first one you don't use the specifiers and in the second one you use specifiers that are not expected.

You can do this:

```
printf("/c=%12f/\nd=%"
       "-12.4f/",c,d);
```